# How to animate a style property in plain vanilla javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, animation

So for a while I've been moving away from jQuery, and in general just reducing my library use where-every possible to a) write leaner code, and b) really understand at a low level whats going on, particularly around the UI.  While I've moved the majority of my UI animation to CSS3, theres often times when you need a little more control, but for a single tiny animation I'd prefer not to always have to pull in velocity.js or greensock etc.

Looking at you-might-not-need-jquery theres a fadeIn function they demostate that looks like this :

```
function fadeIn(el) {
  el.style.opacity = 0;

  var last = +new Date();
  var tick = function() {
    el.style.opacity = +el.style.opacity + (new Date() - last) / 400;
    last = +new Date();

    if (+el.style.opacity < 1) {
      (window.requestAnimationFrame && requestAnimationFrame(tick)) ||     setTimeout(tick, 16);
    }
  };

  tick();
}

fadeIn(el);
```

I generally understand this function, but have a few questions on very specific items :

1. What does the `+` before `new Date()` and `el.style.opacity` on lines 3,5,6 & 8 indicate?  is it something like `+=` ?
2. On line 5, why the division by 400?
3. Is there anything inherently wrong with this recursive requestAnimationFrame technique for general quick animations?

If I understand the concept behind this pattern :

1. we set our starting position (force feeding) and time we're beginning,
2. we then update the style relevant to the amount of time thats passed,
3. until the final state is satisfied, call tick again, on the next animation frame.

Is this correct?

Comment: _1. What does the + before..._ Forced type-casting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. A unary `+` is a quick way to force a value to be interpreted as a number.
2. The division by `400` is the way that code sets the rate of fade-in. A bigger number would make the fade take longer, and a smaller number would make it faster. The number gives the number of milliseconds that will elapse (more or less) before the element is fully opaque.
3. It's not recursive. The reference to the function is passed to the timer mechanism (either `setTimeout()` or `requestAnimationFrame()`) but by the time the timer fires the original call will have exited.

Comment: 1 - awesome, 2 - could you explain the math behind this? or do you have a reference ?, 3 - as the timer then calls the same function again and again is this not recursion?

Comment: @pushplaybang well it's just computing the number of milliseconds between the current time and the time recorded when the process started. It then divides that by 400. So, if only 20 milliseconds have gone by, the opacity value will be `20/400` or `0.05`.  After 100 milliseconds, the opacity will be set to `0.25`, etc.

Comment: And it's not recursion because the function does not directly call itself. Instead, it asks the timer mechanism to call it in the future. When that call happens, the original call will have completed.

Comment: Got it, okay, great on both counts - THANK YOU.